# How to exclude page from Redis cache?

Tags: caching

I'm using [Redis](http://drupal.org/project/redis) and need one dynamic page to be excluded from being cached. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are generating this dynamic page, but somewhere in the mix, you could put something along the lines of:

```
drupal_set_header('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=0');       // set max age to 0
drupal_set_header('Expires', 'Sun, 18 Dec 1983 02:28:00 GMT'); // some date in the distant past
```

before any other output, eg, at the top/start of your page's menu callback or in right before you select its custom template if it has one.

If this doesn't work, a quick hack would be to do a `drupal_set_message('Welcome to my dynamic page');` which would cause drupal's core functions to try not to cache the page :)

Comment: Thanks Jim, I haven't yet tried your option, but I found a solution for my problem. The page was driven by Views so I went to Views settings and turned off caching there. It was that simple. If anyone is looking for it, it's at the bottom of the Advanced section.

Answer (score 0):

How about this snippet in `hook_init()`?

```
$cache_class = variable_get('cache_class_cache', NULL);
if (isset($cache_class) && class_exists($cache_class)) {
  // Check if Redis is being actively used as a cache backend
  if ($cache_class == 'Redis_Cache') {
    if (TRUE) { // Add condition here for your page
      drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amarnath, According to [Drupal API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) hook_init() is not called on cached pages. Instead you should use hook_boot()

Comment: Also look at http://drupal.org/project/cacheexclude